# Ctypes get array from pointer (Mightex camera frame grabbing)

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I need to grab USB camera frame (`int` array of 0-255 values) from pointer address

According to camera function:

```
byte *BUFUSB_GetCurrentFrame(int deviceID, int FrameType, byte * &FramePtr );
```

I need to pass `int deviceID`, `int FrameType` and pointer for frame size (the size should be written in Python)

the function will return address pointer and I need to read frame from the address +frame size.

the frame size is 1280*1024 +56 bytes =1310776
The function I wrote:

```
def GetCurrentFrame(deviceID,FrameType):
    Open=mightex.BUFUSB_GetCurrentFrame
    Open.argtypes =[ctypes.c_int32,ctypes.c_int32,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)]
    Open.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)
    Data=ctypes.c_byte(1310776)
    array_pointer= Open(deviceID,FrameType,ctypes.byref(Data))
    data_pointer = ctypes.cast(array_pointer,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int*1310776))
    print np.frombuffer(data_pointer.contents)
```

From header file:

```
#define SDK_POINTER_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) unsigned char * _cdecl
SDK_POINTER_API BUFUSB_GetCurrentFrame( int FrameType, int deviceID, byte* &FramePtr );
```

According to camera manufacturer:
it returns a pointer as the function’s return value and its third argument to a block of memory which contains:

maybe i should pass memory block instad of the size of memory block??

something wrong in my function it doesn't work please assist

Comment: `byte * &FramePtr` isn't C.  `ctypes` works with C exports not C++.

Comment: but i can read other function from DLL without problem... can it be all function in C and 1 function in C++ from same DLL?

Comment: `extern "C"` isn't C either, so the DLL is actually written in C++, but the function is exported with C linkage.  A pointer reference might be treated as a pointer pointer in that case.  I'd have to test this.  Try `POINTER(POINTER(c_BYTE))` as the type of that parameter.  That interface is not well written.  You wouldn't be able to compile it in strict C.

Comment: Hi Mark, What rows from my code should i change?